# Routine for compressing folders in Visual studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2005, compression, tar, embedded-linux

I am trying to write a routine that compress folder/multiple files for Embedded applications in Visual studio.For that I thought of using combination of zlib and tar.I could successfully run the zlib in visual studio but in case of tar the source code refers to some linux headers and results in error.I am a newbie in this area.Could any one tell me how to create the routine.I found a UnxUtils (sourceforge, GNU utilities for Win32 http://unxutils.sourceforge.net.) while browsing,Is that useful? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hey, i've got the same problem. Nice if this could find an answer

Answer (score 1):

You might also look at [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) library, as it *may* work in your situation.

Quote:

> **Is this thing supported on Mono/Linux?**
>   It's not supported at all. But, it apparently works on Mono/Ubuntu. I don't test it that way. If you'd like to volunteer, let me know.

Comment: Second this.  First, tar doesn't support compression, only archiving, so it may not be what you're looking for anyway.  I recently had need for compression in one of my programs and DotNetZip works excellently.

Comment: Well, the question is really about **uncompressed** concatenation

Comment: @Cyan There's some source code here which may be of interest to you: http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/srcview.aspx?dir=Tar&file=Readme.txt  (Related to, but not included in DotNetZip)

Comment: @mootinator : thanks, it looks interesting. I'll look into it.